# Modifying a member of a struct in a vector if another member of that struct is known

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Disclaimer: I tried searching both online generally and here specifically. If this question has been answered already, please redirect me and close this one.

I have a coding problem and I'm trying to solve it with the following code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("gifts1.in", ios::in);
    ofstream fout("gifts1.out", ios::out);

    unsigned short NP;

    struct person
    {
        string name;
        unsigned int gave;
        unsigned int received;
    };

    vector<person> accounts;

    string tmp_name;
    person buf_person;

    fin >> NP;
    accounts.resize(NP);
    for (auto i : accounts)
    {
        fin >> tmp_name;
        i.name = tmp_name;
        i.gave = i.received = 0;
    }

    for (auto j : accounts)
    {
        string name;
        fin >> name;

        unsigned int sum, people;
        fin >> sum >> people;
        j.gave = sum;
        if (people != 0)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < people; i++)
            {
                string receiver_name;
                fin >> receiver_name;
                accounts.receiver_name.received = sum / people;   // no idea here
            }

            j.gave -= sum % people;   // if a person meant to give 200, but couldn't divide 3,
            // he actually gave 197
        }
    }

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    exit(0);
}
```

The inner `for` loop is supposed to work like this: I'm given a `string receiver_name`, I'm searching in a vector for a particular `person` struct that has this name as a `name` member and change its `received` member.

The question is: is this possible and how do I do it if it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector<person>::iterator it = std::find_if(accounts.begin(), accounts.end(),
  [&receiver_name](const person& p) { return p.name == receiver_name; });
if (it == accounts.end()) {
  // No person with this name
} else {
  person& found = *it;
  // Do what you need here.
}
```

Comment: It looks both elegant and cryptic. 
Also, please clarify: is this a lambda?

Comment: To clarify: this piece of code does, indeed, use a lambda.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I probably have to learn more about them.
For future generations that might find this piece of code: `std::find_if` is in `<algorithm>`